# Oracle - Cannot fetch using table function on type-table, ORA-06504

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to use custom type-table instead of temp table, I can open cursor fine, but I cannot fetch into the original type nor its type-table(i).

ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match.

```
create or replace type ty_PKG_CHA03AA_012B_excp_rpt is object (
    row_no               number,
    err_msg              VARCHAR2(100),
    client_cd            VARCHAR2(8),
    agt_sta              VARCHAR2(1),
    dist_chan            VARCHAR2(10),
    fst_lu_dt            date,
    dsgn_cd              VARCHAR2(4)--,
    --CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION ty_PKG_CHA03AA_012B_excp_rpt RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/

create or replace type tbl_PKG_CHA03AA_012B_excp_rpt is table of ty_PKG_CHA03AA_012B_excp_rpt;
/

declare
    f_err_cd    varchar2(4);
    f_err_len   number;

    f_fst_sl_no number;
    f_wk_err    def.wk_err%type;

    l_cur tbl_PKG_CHA03AA_012B_excp_rpt := tbl_PKG_CHA03AA_012B_excp_rpt();
    o_excp_rpt ty_PKG_CHA03AA_012B_excp_rpt := ty_PKG_CHA03AA_012B_excp_rpt(0,'','','','',null,'');
    l_count number := 1;

    fi_date_fr date;
    fi_wk_no varchar2(10);
    o_excp_rpt_cur sys_refcursor;
    col_count        number := 1;

begin
    if ((fi_date_fr is null) or (trim(fi_date_fr) = '')) then
        fi_date_fr := sysdate;
    end if;

    if ((fi_wk_no is null) or (trim(fi_wk_no) = '')) then
        o_excp_rpt.err_msg := 'The parameter wk_no is empty.';
        --return o_excp_rpt.err_msg;
    end if;

    select nvl(min(sl_no),0)
      into f_fst_sl_no
      from def
     where to_date(last_upd_dt) = fi_date_fr
       and wk_no = fi_wk_no;

    l_cur.extend;
    for l_camw in (
        select client_cd, fst_lu_dt, wk_err, sl_no
          into o_excp_rpt.client_cd, o_excp_rpt.fst_lu_dt, f_wk_err, o_excp_rpt.row_no
          from def
         where to_date(last_upd_dt) = fi_date_fr
           and wk_no = fi_wk_no
           and wk_sta = 'E') loop

        select nvl(agt_sta,''), nvl(dist_chan,''), nvl(dsgn_cd,'')
          into o_excp_rpt.agt_sta, o_excp_rpt.dist_chan, o_excp_rpt.dsgn_cd      
          from abc
         where client_cd = o_excp_rpt.client_cd;

        if ((f_wk_err is not null) and (trim(f_wk_err)  '')) then
            o_excp_rpt.row_no := o_excp_rpt.row_no - f_fst_sl_no + 1;        
            f_err_len := length(f_wk_err)/5;
            for f_idx in 1 .. f_err_len loop
                f_err_cd := substr(f_wk_err, 5 * (f_idx - 1) + 1, 4);

                if ((f_err_cd is not null) and (f_err_cd  '')) then
                    select nvl(msg_desc, '') into o_excp_rpt.err_msg
                        from message where msg_code = f_err_cd;

                end if;
                l_cur(l_count) := o_excp_rpt;
                l_count := l_count + 1;
            end loop;
        end if;

    end loop;

    --open o_excp_rpt_cur for select * from table(l_cur);
    open o_excp_rpt_cur for select row_no, err_msg, client_cd, agt_sta,
        dist_chan, fst_lu_dt, dsgn_cd from table(l_cur);
    loop
        --fetch o_excp_rpt_cur into l_cur(col_count);
        fetch o_excp_rpt_cur into o_excp_rpt;
        exit when o_excp_rpt_cur%notfound;
        col_count := col_count + 1;
        dbms_output.put_line('L' || col_count || 'L');
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('Z' || col_count || 'Z');
end;
```

Comment: please post the whole block of code.

Comment: brenners1302, see blow for whole block of code

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting clarifications as answers.  I believe I have edited your question correctly but please verify.  I assume that your error is occurring on the line `fetch o_excp_rpt_cur into o_excp_rpt;`?

Comment: Yes, and I would like to know why.  But I think posting the code is actually more confusing than my actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of things about your code that confuse me including the fact that you only have one call to `extend`.  Your variable naming conventions are also rather confusing.

When you want to iterate through the collection, though, just iterate through the collection.  There is no need to take the collection, send it from PL/SQL to SQL, just to get it back into PL/SQL.  Just

```
FOR i IN 1..l_cur.count
LOOP
  col_count := col_count + 1;
  dbms_output.put_line( l_cur(i).row_no );
END LOOP;
```

In your actual loop, you're not doing anything with the data in the collection so it wouldn't make sense to even iterate through the loop.  Just set

```
col_count := l_cur.count;
```

I added the `dbms_output.put_line( l_cur(i).row_no );` so that the loop was actually doing something with the data in the collection.

Based on your comment, if you really want to return a `sys_refcursor` by pulling data from the SQL VM into the PL/SQL VM just to pass it back to the SQL VM to return it back to the PL/SQL VM (this will be costly if we're talking about a lot of data), your calling code can fetch the data into separate scalar variables,

```
fetch l_your_cursor
 into l_row_no, 
      l_err_msg, 
      ...
```

Or you could define a cursor that returns rows of your object type by calling an object constructor

```
open l_rc
 for select ty_PKG_CHA03AA_012B_excp_rpt( <<list of attributes>> )
       from table( l_cur );
```

Comment: That's why I don't see the point on posting the code.  The cusor on the sql statement is supposed to return from a function.  The script posted is just for testing purpose!

Comment: @wez - It helps to post code that shows what you actually want to do.  Otherwise, we're forced to do a lot of guessing.  I expanded my answer based on your comment.

Comment: thanks for the help, I was hoping the syntax would be more seamless.  And I was getting the impression that I can fetch into a "collection" without the type constructor.  Cheers.

Comment: @wez - You can fetch into a collection relatively easily just by doing a `bulk collect` without needing to call an object constructor.  That doesn't appear to be what you are asking here.